# Unicity of values in R

Tags: r

I need some help with R.
I'm not an expert and just began using it.

I need to check the unicity of values in a table and would like to know how I can do that.

Let say I have a contractID and a contractNumber in the data frame Contract2008
I would like to make sure that there is only 1 contractNumber by Contract ID.
I did this :

```
DT <- data.table(contract2008)
DT[, .(number_of_distinct_numcontract = length(unique("contractNumeber"))), by = "ContractID"]
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You could use the base function `duplicated()` which returns a binary vector with `TRUE` when the item is a duplicate.

Comment: @RLearner Welcome at SO and thanks for providing example R code to your question! Please always also add minimal example data to your example code and show the expected result to make your question clearer. THX!